# Encapsular conexões TClientSocket em Multithreads

Tags: delphi, socket, multithreading

Tenho um numero X variável de equipamentos eletrônicos (estações Meteorológicas) na minha rede local, cada equipamento fornece uma conexão ServerSocket com um IP e uma Porta específica, tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em DELPHI XE5 que se conecta a todos esses equipamentos, minha aplicação sabe quais são os IPs e Portas destes equipamentos, pois estão cadastrados no banco de dados, ao abrir minha aplicação, crio dinamicamente uma conexão [TClientSocket (Array)] para cada um destes equipamentos, aos quais posteriormente troco uma série de informações, como uma conversa, pergunto a temperatura a todos os equipamentos e eles me respondem, ou posso pedir a temperatura pra um deles, a umidade pra outro, a velocidade do vento pra outro etc... através de OPERAÇÕES internas.

Hoje faço um laço FOR de todos os equipamentos conectados e a partir disto sei qual operação com o equipamento meu software está e então faço a conversa de forma aleatória com cada equipamento, mas isto é lento, pois conforme aumenta o numero de equipamentos, aumenta a lentidão do FOR. O que quero fazer é uma Thread para eliminar o FOR, gostaria de saber se isso é possível. Os eventos onConnect, OnRead, etc... do meu TClientScojet são atribuídos na criação do TClientSocket Array, portanto acabo tendo essa espera de um usar, depois o outro e não consigo atender todos os equipamentos ao mesmo tempo.

Gostaria de poder usar Thread pra isso e atender todos os equipamentos ao mesmo tempo, mas não domino o conceito e a utilização.

**[ATUALIZADO]**

Link do source completo, não postei aqui pois passa de mil linhas:

https://mega.co.nz/#!bAVBwTAb!fdzyS9ENPMWul3wC8GFkKATiJ7whKB7Xzgo5FUHlD6M

Hoje utilizo esta classe que criei estendida da TClientSocket:

```
type
  TTermoCenter = class(TClientSocket)
  private
    countSema: Thandle;
    access: TCriticalSection;
    ...
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Push(inObject: TPalavra; priority: Integer); virtual;
    function Pop(pResObject: pObject; timeout: Integer): Boolean;
  end;
```

Aqui está o constructor:

```
constructor TTermoCenter.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  access := TCriticalSection.Create;
  ...
end;
```

Aqui está o destructor:

```
destructor TTermoCenter.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ...
  access.Free;
  closeHandle(countSema);
  inherited;
end;
```

declaração da variável:

```
var
  termocenters: array of TTermoCenter;
```

Ao criar o meu Form, defino o tamanho do meu Array

```
SetLength(termocenters, dm.sqlTermocenter.RecordCount);
```

E crio as minhas conexões baseada no que está no banco de dados:
    var
      SocketTmp: TTermoCenter;

```
  while not cds.Eof do
  begin
    SocketTmp := TTermoCenter.Create(nil);
    SocketTmp.name := 'cdsNome';
    SocketTmp.Port := 'cdsPorta';
    SocketTmp.ClientType := ctNonBlocking;
    SocketTmp.Host := 'cdsIP';
    // atribui eventos
    SocketTmp.OnRead := TCPRead;
    SocketTmp.OnConnect := TCPConnect;
    SocketTmp.OnDisconnect := TCPDisconnect;
    SocketTmp.OnError := TCPError;

    //Coloca no Array
    termocenters[I] := SocketTmp;
    try
      termocenters[I].Active := True;
      sleep(1000);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        frmMain.mmErros.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(now) + ' - ' + E.ClassName + ' CriaConexao : ' + E.Message);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  cds.Next;
end;
end;
```

Esse é um código bem resumido do que tenho hoje, gostaria de uma ajuda pra implementar Threads.

Comment: Mesmo com threads você ainda precisará de um for, acredito. No entanto as conexões serão feitas de forma paralela. Não conheço nada de Delphi, mas espero que você consiga boas respostas.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, dá pra identificar duas necessidades nesta pergunta: a) Conceito e utilização de threads em Delphi. b) Implementar neste sistema o uso threads para comunicação paralela com as estações meteorológicas. Para o item "a", recomendo este artigo: http://devutils.blogspot.com/2009/01/threads-conceito-e-exemplo.html. Para o item "b", recomendo tentar a implementação a partir da leitura do artigo e daí postar aqui as dificuldades encontradas. Faz sentido?

Comment: @Caffé faz todo o sentido, é isto mesmo que quero.

Comment: Segue o Source completo https://mega.co.nz/#!bAVBwTAb!fdzyS9ENPMWul3wC8GFkKATiJ7whKB7Xzgo5FUHlD6M

Comment: Qual a versão do Delphi que você está utilizando, no XE7 existem muitos facilitadores para threads. Você deveria quebrar sua pergunta em várias perguntas específicas. "se alguém souber como posso melhorar este código, fico muito grato.", threading é um conceito complexo que envolve várias teorias e regras, não peça pelo código pronto, você deveria ir tentando e postando perguntas a cada demanda de dúvidas. Para começar [leia esses artigos](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/14809). Nota: Está em inglês.

Comment: @AlexSchmitt O meu comentário anterior expõe a mecânica do StackOverflow. Você precisar deixar a pergunta mais específica. Veja que não sou o único a conhecer esta mecânica (óbvio e felizmente) de modo que sua pergunta foi suspensa pela comunidade. Sinta-se convidado a participar do StackOverflow sempre que achar válido trabalhar de acordo com a comunidade (a qual não trata indivíduos e sim perguntas e respostas).

Answer (score 3):

Vou concordar com o @PageNotFound, que sua questão está muito ampla e aguardando um código funcional.

Posso lhe dar uns passos para guiar. Segue um exemplo usando Generics, Annonymous Methods e um recurso de Thread anônimas:

A idéia é ter um pool de conexões e ter um método que cria uma Worker thread para cada conexão para realizar uma tarefa específica

```
interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections, Datasnap.Win.SConnect;

type
  TPoolConexoes = class(TObjectList<TSocketConnection>)
  private
    procedure SeuMetodoQueUsaConexao(const aConexao: TSocketConnection);
  public
    function NewConnection: TSocketConnection;
    function ObterConexoesPorStatus(const aStatus: string): TPoolConexoes;

    procedure ExecutarSeuMetodoParaLista(const Conexoes: TPoolConexoes);
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.Classes;

{ TPoolConexoes }

procedure TPoolConexoes.ExecutarSeuMetodoParaLista(const Conexoes: TPoolConexoes);
var
  conexao: TSocketConnection;
  threadAtual: TThread;
begin
  for conexao in Conexoes do
  begin
    threadAtual := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        Self.SeuMetodoQueUsaConexao(conexao);
      end
    );
    threadAtual.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    threadAtual.Start;
  end;

end;

function TPoolConexoes.NewConnection: TSocketConnection;
var
  conexaoTemp: TSocketConnection;
begin
  conexaoTemp := TSocketConnection.Create(nil);
  Self.Add(conexaoTemp);
  Result := conexaoTemp;
end;

function TPoolConexoes.ObterConexoesPorStatus(const aStatus: string): TPoolConexoes;
begin
  //sua logica aqui
end;

procedure TPoolConexoes.SeuMetodoQueUsaConexao(const aConexao: TSocketConnection);
begin
  //usa a conexao para fazer algo
end;

end.
```

Você ainda pode colocar todas as thread criadas em uma ThreadList e gerenciar o fim delas

Ou pode estender a classe de thread para conter o código da execução ao invés de usar os anonimos e manter as threads em um pool que irá executando OnDemand

Tudo depende das suas necessidades

Comment: Obrigado amigo, segue o link do Source 

https://mega.co.nz/#!bAVBwTAb!fdzyS9ENPMWul3wC8GFkKATiJ7whKB7Xzgo5FUHlD6M